# Field value query and filed range query, result not matching

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-10

I am getting different result when I execute below query, `cts:field-value-query` is returning `10355058` count and `cts:field-range-query` or `cts:path-range-query` is returing `12189408` count, so I am not sure why is this difference in count ?.

```
let $query1 := cts:field-value-query("item",("A", "B"))
let $query2 := cts:field-range-query("item", "=", ("A", "B"))
    return (  
            xdmp:estimate( cts:search(fn:doc(), $query1)), 
            xdmp:estimate( cts:search(fn:doc(), $query2)) 
            )
```

Comment: You are literally searching for "A" and "B"? And the XML elements or JSON properties matching that "item" field just have those values? i.e. `<doc><item>A</item></doc>`

Comment: Hello, Yes I am searching for those docs where item value is A or B, it is a XML element.

Comment: Wondering if it could be something such as leading/trailing whitespace or punctuation characters that are being ignored by the cts:field-value-query and counted in the estimate, but do not match exactly when using cts:field-range-query. For instance: `<item>A-</item>`

Comment: Rewrite your query to return some samples of docs that exist in one query and not the other. Then start investigating the content.  Don't trust your eyes - convert the values to unicode codepoint values as well.   In addition, consider that this example is all through a field, that perhaps has settings that make a difference as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your valuable comments, following query worked and got correct result by applying `('unstemmed')` query option.

```
let $query1 := cts:field-value-query("item",("A", "B"),('unstemmed'))
let $query2 := cts:field-range-query("item", "=", ("A", "B"))
    return (  
            xdmp:estimate( cts:search(fn:doc(), $query1)), 
            xdmp:estimate( cts:search(fn:doc(), $query2)) 
            )
```